# Automatic select a date in datepicker in Swift language

Tags: swift, nsdate, uidatepicker

I have a date "Thursday, 18 Sep 2014" in this format. when I click a "change date" button. how we can automatic select a this date in datepicker in Swift language.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var dateString = "Thursday, 18 Sep 2014"
var df = NSDateFormatter()
df.dateFormat = "eeee, dd MM yyyy"
var date = df.dateFromString(dateString)
if let unwrappedDate = date {
    datePicker.setDate(unwrappedDate, animated: false)
}
```