# UIDatePicker Click done and display text

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker

I would like to get the date after the UIPicker pop-up and straight away click done button to display the date on "dobTxt.text" without scroll and select the date from UIDatePicker. How to do it?

[image]

```
   func doneBtnForDate(){

    if (dobTxt.text == "Please select your DOB"){
         //let selectedDate = How to get picker date without scroll it?
         dobTxt.text = selectedDate
    }

    picker.isHidden = true
    toolBar2.isHidden = true
    datePicker.isHidden = true
}
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25859432/automatic-select-a-date-in-datepicker-in-swift-langauge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `doneBtnForDate` like below

```
func doneBtnForDate(){

    if (dobTxt.text == "Please select your DOB"){
         //let selectedDate = How to get picker date without scroll it?
         dobTxt.text = selectedDate
    }

   // IF you want to change date formatting then you need to change in "DateFormatter" below 
   let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .full
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = .full
    let strDate = dateFormatter.string(from: yourPicker.date)  
    dobTxt.text = strDate

    picker.isHidden = true
    toolBar2.isHidden = true
    datePicker.isHidden = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is objective c Code for it.

```
     [datepicker addTarget:self  action:@selector(DateChange:)
            forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    //method for change date

    - (void)DateChange:(id)sender
{
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
        label.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:datepicker.date];
        date.text=strDate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please set `dobTxt.inputView = picker` in `viewDidLoad` method

It works fine for me. Hope it will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
func doneBtnForDate()
{
    if (dobTxt.text == "Please select your DOB")
    {
         let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
         dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
         dobTxt.text = dateFormatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
    }

    picker.isHidden = true
    toolBar2.isHidden = true
    datePicker.isHidden = true
}
```